# Image cropper dependancy not working how do I configure it on my gradle?

Tags: java, android

just added this dependancy api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0' and im getting

```
Failed to resolve: com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.5.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

so how do I go about it. Anybody with the same experience please share.

Comment: The error doesn't seem to match the dependency. Could you please copy the gradle.build file and the [complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) in the question?

Comment: Dependencies that start with com.github are not normal dependencies, they require to add the repository gitpack.io

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.